# Consume Go cgo generated shared object file from Go application

Tags: go, cgo

I'm generating a Go library as shared object (c-shared mode). The goal is to provide the library as closed source. There was a `binary-only-package` in previous version of Go, but this is not supported anymore. The library approach would be the only option I'm aware of except this.

One of the functions define in the Go library is:

```golang
func OPP_acquire_context(name string, handle *uint64) C.struct_OPP_Result
```

In the generated header by cgo file after running `go build -o libopp.so -buildmode=c-shared opp.go` the exported function is declared as:

```c
extern OPP_Result OPP_acquire_context(GoString name, GoUint64* handle);
```

I can write a C sample application using the library and it works. But when trying to write us a Go client (using `import "C"`) the `GoString` typedef is not found. I get:

> cgo-gcc-export-header-prolog:60:44: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before 'GoString'

Since a client might also use a Go environment to use the library it would be required to also be usable from Go code. Can a Go library build by cgo used by a Go application? Is offering Go a different way to distribute closed source libraries?

Comment: Loading another go runtime into a go program is not supported, so you cannot reliably use cgo to create an ad-hoc plugin system. Go does not support sourceless libraries, but you could make use of binary plugins like `hashicorp/go-plugin`

Comment: @JimB This would be then a [plugin](https://pkg.go.dev/plugin)? The usage and call conventions are not very simple. This is the only way for closed sources?

Comment: No, the `plugin` package requires both the main binary and the plug-in to be built with the exact same toolchain version, which makes separate distribution awkward at best. `github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin` uses separate binaries communicating via grpc.